# Drop Down List SelectedIndexChanged event handler fires multiple times inside ListView control

Tags: asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have a list view control which I am binding using `DataTable`. In the `ItemDataBound` I am creating `DropDownList` and adding items programmatically and binding `SelectedIndexChanged` event to that drop down.

In my case, suppose three rows are created in the ListView and there are three Drop Downs in the list view. When I change the drop down selection to first `DropDownList` then `SelectedIndexChanged` fires one time. Then I change the selection in second `DropDownList` then `SelectedIndexChanged` fires two times and then I change the selection in second `DropDownList` then `SelectedIndexChanged` fires three times.

```
protected void dlMain_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView currentRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        Panel pnl = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlUser");
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            pnl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(currentRow.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString()));
        }
        Panel pnlDropDown = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlDropDown");
        if (pnlDropDown != null)
        {
            if (dtCustomers.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow[] customers = dtCustomers.Select("KItemId = " + Convert.ToInt32(currentRow.Row.ItemArray[0]) + "");
                if (customers.Length > 0)
                {
                    DropDownList customerDDL = new DropDownList();
                    ListItem baseItem = new ListItem("-- Select --", "0");
                    customerDDL.Items.Add(baseItem);
                    foreach (DataRow customerRow in customers)
                    {
                        ListItem newItem = new ListItem(customerRow["CustName"].ToString(), customerRow["CustId"].ToString());
                        customerDDL.Items.Add(newItem);
                    }
                    customerDDL.ID = "Customers" + Convert.ToString(currentRow.Row.ItemArray[0]);
                    customerDDL.AutoPostBack = true;
                    customerDDL.SelectedIndexChanged += customerDDL_SelectedIndexChanged;
                    pnlDropDown.Controls.Add(customerDDL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To check the behavior of event I wrote the single line of code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
void customerDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList changedList = (DropDownList)sender;

}
```

Here when I fist change the selected value of DropDown1 then I am getting the `ID` DropDown1 then I change the selected value of DropDown2  the event fires two times and in first time I am getting id of sender object DrowDown1 and then again control comes in the event and I get the sender object DropDown2.

What should I do to get the exact control's selected item in the `SelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this like this...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                int[] arr = { 1, 3, 5 };
                ListView1.DataSource = arr;
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlval.Text = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
        }
        protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem  )
                {


                    DropDownList ddl = e.Item.FindControl("ddl") as DropDownList;
                    ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);

                }

        }
```

ASPX page

```
<asp:listview id="ListView1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" xmlns:asp="#unknown">  
         <LayoutTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="2" width="680px" border="0">
                <tr id="Tr1" style="background-color: #ADD8E6" runat="server">                   
                    <th id="Th3" runat="server">
                        E-mail Address
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </table>

        </LayoutTemplate>     
         <itemtemplate>
            <tr id="Tr2" style="background-color: #CAEEFF" runat="server">

                <td>
                   <asp:dropdownlist id="ddl" runat="server" autopostback="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:listitem text="Select 1" value="One" selected="True">Review</asp:listitem>
                <asp:listitem text="Select 2" value="Two">Send Back to Level1</asp:listitem>
            </asp:dropdownlist>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </itemtemplate>

</asp:listview>
<asp:label id="ddlval" text="test" runat="server"></asp:label>
```

I have modified my code...and it's working at my local...

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your suggested way but getting the same result. i.e. when I change the section in the second drop down then the event fires two times. :-(

Comment: Hello sir,if I place `Page.IsPostBack` condition then the rendering of control disappears when first time page loads

Comment: sorry..remove page.IsPostBack

Comment: yes sir, after removing the condition the output is same, that `SelectedIndexChanged` fires more than once.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent firing handler, multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for answering sir, javascript code perfectly